# CSS - Two CSS file having same class not loading properly

Tags: html, css

I have two css files having the following class definition

default.css ( Loaded First )

```
#order-standard_cart .products .product header {
    background: #f8f8f8 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    margin: 0 1px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
}
```

custom.css ( Loaded 2nd )

```
#order-standard_cart .products .product header {
    background: #7EBBF3 none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
```

Even after loading second, the background property is not getting applied on any of the browsers and only the first CSS file is being applied.

[image: CSS File Import]

[image: Firebug CSS Output]

Comment: Please provide a link to the website.

Comment: Added in the main post

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Preferably as a snippet here in the question. The website itself contains too many elements and styles to pinpoint the problem, and besides, since you're currently working on it, it may soon no longer match the problem description in the question. In addition, creating a [mcve] may well help you solve the case yourself.

Comment: line 213 in your html code overrides your custom styles.

Comment: Yes, the offending line is indeed in a later stylesheet than the one you think it is in. @Banzay, why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @Banzay Thanks, I found it I wonder why the WHMCS team added this same css code again. 

Please post this as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: that's not the same. those are two fully different files with defferent paths but the same name.

Comment: Yes, I see it.  made changes carefully :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 213 in your html code overrides your custom styles

at the header of page file all.css is loaded from `payments/templates/six/css/` relative path

line 213 loads file all.css from `/payments/templates/orderforms/standard_cart/css/`

Comment: Yup! I see it.  Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You include the file `all.min.css?v=6235b7` a second time on line 213 and thus the selector from this file has greater priority and overwrite the selector from `custom.css`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but @Banzay provided the solution first so his answer was accepted :)

Comment: I lost a few seconds because I tried to provide you with a printscreen then changed my mind.